# How to remove and add a content with a single button in JPanel Java Gui?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I wrote a code that visualise some Cities with random x and y values, if i press on the button RandomB.Firstly I want it to clear the Screen so i used
`Screen.removeAll();  Screen.revalidate();  Screen.repaint();`
for the Job.
I then return the function in forLoop to create some cities getSA is the Number of cities.But the problem is after I run the proggramm and press the button i see the cities but they disappear very fast.I sometiemes dont even see them What could be the Problem??

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       
        //if (e.getSource() == starButton) {
            
        //}
        
        if (e.getSource() == randomB) {
            Screen.removeAll();
            Screen.revalidate();
            Screen.repaint();
            getSA = StadtAnzahl.getSelectedItem().toString();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(getSA); i++) {
                int x = r.nextInt((int) Math.round(0.77 * screenSize.width)) + 10;
                int y = r.nextInt((int) Math.round(0.82 * screenSize.height)) + 10;
                ZeichneStadt(x, y, Screen.getGraphics());                
            }
        
        }
    }
    public void ZeichneStadt(int x,int y,Graphics g)
    {
       Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g.create();
       g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
       g2.setColor(Color.red);
       g2.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
       salesman.hinzufügen(x, y);
    }
```

I tried to replace removeall(),revalidiate() and repaint().

Comment: You're doing your painting wrong. I suggest you take the Swing painting tutorial. Also, it looks like you're tearing down your gui. There's seldom a good reason for doing that and you should avoid it

Comment: Do not call `getGraphics()`, ever.  It will not allow you to draw to the screen.  Instead, you must override `paintComponent` and use the Graphics object provided by the system to that method.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ for all the details.

Comment: `Screen.getGraphics()` is a bad idea

Comment: *I want it to clear the Screen* - if you need the ability to paint multiple objects, then keep an ArrayList of the objects you want to paint. Then to clear the screen you would simply remove all the Objects form the List. Check out the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a complete working example demonstrating this concept.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a `paintComponent()` method which will paint data from a variable onto the screen. Be aware that `paintComponent()` is not called by you. It is up to Swing to decide when a component needs to be painted.

In your `actionPerformed()` method prepare the data that shall be painted (=put them into a variable), but then you just call `repaint()`. This indicates to Swing that the data has changed and the component should be repainted. Swing will check if the component is visible at all, and only then call `paintComponent()`.